# Why aren't inherited scope options replicating between Win2019 DHCP servers in a failover config?

Tags: dhcp, failover, windows-server-2019

I have 2 Win 2019 DCs, both running DHCP servers with a scope configured for failover. If I explicitly set scope options on one, they properly replicate to the other server. But options inherited from the server options do not replicate (nor do server level options). Is this the expected behavior? This seems very undesirable. I am just prototyping now, but I will eventually have 8-9 scopes, all of which will share most options in common, so it would be nice to configure and maintain those at the server options level.

Related -- the settings only seem to replicate when I manually request replication, but I assume this should happen automatically. I cannot find any documentation of the default replication interval. How often should they be automatically replicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug, I just encountered it in 2022 so it's not fixed.  You can use DFACS and set a scheduled task to automate it.

https://sjohnonline.blogspot.com/2018/12/dhcp-failover-auto-config-sync-dfacs.html?showComment=1621408500425#c4847247760134534983

Fix download and info:  https://web.archive.org/web/20201204144834/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Auto-syncing-of-configurati-6eb54fb0
https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/400812/dhcp-failover-auto-config-sync-dfacs.html